In how many ways can the letters of the word "INFORMATIKA" be arranged if the string "AA" can't appear
The answer for just the number of different permutations is $\frac{11!}{2!2!}$ because we have 2 I's and 2 A's.
But "AA" can't appear - for example, 'IAANFORMTIK" wouldn't be allowed but 'IANFORMATIK" would.
I'm assuming the solution involves looking at "AA" as one character ( which would be $\frac{10!}{2!}$ ), but I can't think of a way to calculate the number of arrangements in which that character doesn't appear. I know the answer is very simple, but I can't figure it out.

I think your approach of considering AA a single symbol is a good start to the problem, but I suppose the answer will depend on if we consider all possible movements of same letters differently. For example there are also two I:s. The resulting string is the same in all cases those two Is get confused but the permutation is not the same. Do we actually ask about how many different operations of movement of the letters or only about how many different resulting strings.

Simply {All permutations} - {permutations with "AA" treated as one character}

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Asked here before

In INFORMATIKA we have
We have a repeated A and repeated I
So total number of permutations are $${11!\over2!2!}=9979200$$
We can find the number of permutations with AA by assuming a new character set INFORMTIK# so when generate permutations like INFOR#MTIK it is equivalent to INFORAAMTIK.
So the number of permutations with AA is$${10!\over2!}=1814400$$
Now we can just subtract the number of permutations with AA from total to get $$9979200-1814400=816480$$
You can generalize this to Inclusion Exclusion

Ah mb changed it thank you
